Not able to create job in dataflow for streaming data
I am executing my Apache-beam code in google cloud shell, I am able to execute code without errors, but jobs not creating in data flow.
**below roles I assigned to service account
**
Dataflow Worker, Dataflow Admin, Pub/Sub Editor, the Storage Object Admin, and the BigQuery Data Editor
**
code I am using below, I am not getting errors when executing this code in cloud shell**
import json
import apache_beam as beam
from datetime import date
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import ReadFromPubSub
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

cus_gcp_temp_loc="gs://sai_sample_bucket"
subscription_name="projects/teg-cloud-bfsi-uk1/subscriptions/s-test-2-sub"
output_table="teg-cloud-bfsi-uk1:tutorial_dataset.s-test-2"

schema="""url:STRING, review:STRING"""

class fun1(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,element):
        try:
            if len(element)==0:
                print("if working")
                raise ValueError("no data")
            else:
                 value=[]
                 print("else its working")
                 return [value]
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

def process_columns(element):
    data=element.decode("UTF-8")
    return json.loads(data)

class table(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        try:
            if len(element)==0:
                raise ValueError("collection is empty")
            else:
                val=[]
                msg=[element['msg']]
                val.extend(msg)

                name=[element['name']]
                val.extend(name)

                return val
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

map=lambda x:{'msg':x[0],'name':x[1]}

def load():
    beam_options=PipelineOptions(
        streaming=True,
        runner='DataflowRunner',
        project='teg-cloud-bfsi-uk1',
        job_name='newjob',
        statging_location='gs://sai_sample_bucket/stage',
        temp_location='gs://sai_sample_bucket/temp',
        template_location="gs://sai_sample_bucket/streamingpipeline",
        region='us-central1')

    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
        input_data=(pipeline | "read from pub/sub" >> ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription_name) 
                             | 'process columns' >> beam.Map(process_columns)
                            #| 'splitting' >> beam.Map(lambda x:x.split(','))
                            #|'aggregation columns'>>beam.ParDo(table())
                            #|'formating column into key value pair' >> beam.Map(map)
                            #| "out" >>beam.Map(print))
                             | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(table=output_table,schema=schema,create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("start")
    load()
    print("END")


help me to create a job in GCP data flow

Does [this](
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#run-on-dataflow
) command help you?
